# Is it possible to get an older Windows version Look-and-Feel in Windows 10?

Tags: java, windows, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I am using Windows 10 and I have a javax.swing application, Its default look and feel is Windows 10. I want to decorate my application with older windows look and feel.

This code

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

It will only return Windows 10 look and feel.

Is it possible to get older windows look and feel?

Answer (score 2):

When I run code to test this, I get the following output:

```
run:
javax.swing.UIManager$LookAndFeelInfo[Metal javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel]
javax.swing.UIManager$LookAndFeelInfo[Nimbus javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel]
javax.swing.UIManager$LookAndFeelInfo[CDE/Motif com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel]
javax.swing.UIManager$LookAndFeelInfo[Windows com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel]
javax.swing.UIManager$LookAndFeelInfo[Windows Classic com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel]
```

It looks like your choices are Windows 10 and "Classic" whatever that is (probably closer to an even earlier version of Windows).  I think you're stuck without a lot of work, unfortunately.

```
package quicktest;

import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Brenden
 */
public class LookAndFeelTest {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info[] = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
      for( int i = 0; i < info.length; i++ ) {
         UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo lookAndFeelInfo = info[i];
         System.out.println( lookAndFeelInfo );
      }
   }
}
```